Find the value of y from the expression $0 =\dfrac{1}{y^2} - x^2 + 2Cx^3 - \dfrac{4aC}{y^3}x$. [Ans. $ y = \dfrac{1}{x} + C - 2aCx $]
Here is my attempt.
$$\begin{align*}
& 0  =\dfrac{1}{y^2} - x^2 + 2Cx^3 - \dfrac{4aC}{y^3}x\\
\Rightarrow & \dfrac{1}{y^2} =  x^2 - 2Cx^3 + \dfrac{4aC}{y^3}x \\
\Rightarrow & \dfrac{1}{y^2} = x^2\left[1 - \left(2Cx - \dfrac{4aC}{y^3x}  \right)\right]\\
\Rightarrow & y = \dfrac{1}{x} \left[1 - \left(2Cx - \dfrac{4aC}{y^3x}  \right)  \right]^{-\frac{1}{2}} \\
 &  \simeq \dfrac{1}{x}\left[1 -\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}  \right) \left(2Cx - \dfrac{4aC}{y^3x}  \right)  \right] \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad {{}  [\because\text{Expanding binomially and neglecting the higher order terms}}] \notag \\
& = \dfrac{1}{x} \left[1 + Cx - \dfrac{2aC}{y^3x}  \right]\\
& = \dfrac{1}{x} + C - \dfrac{2aC}{y^3}\dfrac{1}{x^2}\\
& \simeq \dfrac{1}{x} + C - 2aCx \\
\Rightarrow y &= \dfrac{1}{x} + C - 2aCx  
\end{align*} $$
What I am having trouble with is (i) having a $y^{-3}$ term in my expression which I am swapping out with $y\simeq \dfrac{1}{x}$. The reason I went with the approach of expansion as shown is because that way I could get the form required in the answer. But the mathematical approach seems a bit iffy. Could you please take a look and check if my approach is actually valid and/or if there is a more robust way of getting the answer.
Note1- $\geq C^2$, $\geq a^2$ terms can be neglected.

What you did is correct.
If you plug the answer in the expression, the result is not $0$; so, the answer is an approximation.
You can make it a bit faster computing the first iterate of Newton method applied to the function
$$F(y)=\dfrac{1}{y^2} - x^2 + 2Cx^3 - \dfrac{4aC}{y^3}x$$ starting with $y_0=\frac 1x$ as you did.
$$y_1=y_0- \frac {F(y_0)} {F'(y_0)}$$
The expression is very simple. Now, there is term that you can neglect using the assumptions about $C$ and $a$.
